# Folder icons in Mac OS Big Sur

Tags: macos, directory, icons, macos-big-sur, icns

I am trying to set the folder icon for a shared folder from /System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/GenericSharepoint.icns
I have observed that none of the .icns files in the path mentioned above have the darker tint of blue on the folder icon which is present for all the folder icons set by the OS in Big Sur.
Can anyone please confirm if this is the correct path to read updated folder icons in Big Sur? Any help in understanding the inconsistency would be appreciated.
[dark blue tint on the folder icons set by OS[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMeXj.jpg)

Comment: This question belongs on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) and it has been asked here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/438900/where-are-the-system-folder-icons-located-in-big-sur-monterey